# A bit of toothpaste?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

My English learner app said "a bit of toothpaste" was wrong but didn't say the reason.
Could you please tell me why?

The app test goes like this.

```
Choose the correct one:
a bit of ______

A)information
B)toothpaste
```

Then only A is the right answer.
I feel both are right.

Answer (score 2):

1. "A bit of toothpaste"
2. "A bit of information"

Both nouns are uncountable but *a bit of information*, i.e. "news", is **the more common collocation**. However, both phrases are perfectly grammatical.

Examples from [here](https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?hardm=1&t=0&l=0&p=3&q=%22a%20bit%20of%22information)

> - Quite a **bit of information** was provided by the local business
> - Yes, one does require **a bit of information** about planes, visas and such.
> - **A bit of Googling** can give you the contact information you need
> - The area received quite **a bit of snow** this past week
> - You need **a bit of luck** in this game
> - How the brain converts speech into meaningful information is **a bit of a puzzle**

Comment: In other words, @i’malittlebus is right? Both A and B are correct and the app is wrong?

Comment: Instead of asking "choose the **correct** one", in my opinion the app should have said "choose the ***best*** one" I found two instances with "toothpaste". 1. *Moisten the silver piece and **apply a bit of toothpaste** to your finger*.  and 2. *If that doesn't work, **a bit of toothpaste** on a dry cloth, and a firm wipe, might do.*

Comment: Ok. I’m not even sure there is a clear “best” here though.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie I should have said the "most common" collocation.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. My argument is with the app - it is an odd and confusing test for an English Learner no matter how you look at it.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that "bit" is also a basic unit of information in information theory, especially in computer science. So a "bit of information" is very much a countable noun in certain contexts.

Comment: @Dallium [edited for clarity] it is the unit called *bit* which is countable not "information". I don't think "Three bits of information**s**" would ever be acceptable in English. And the last answer that suggested "bit" was the correct **formal** term for measuring information technology (IT), which it is but "a (little) bit" is also used with innumerable other nouns, got downvoted three times and its owner deleted the post.

Answer (score 1):

It’s fine to say in British English, “a bit of" is a common collocation here to mean "a small amount of something":

## The Guardian:

> I am a voice on the radio, that is all. No one knows what I look like. I can go to work in my jeans and jumper with **a bit of toothpaste** down the front and no one is any the wiser
>
> Source: https://www.theguardian.com/society/2012/may/12/alice-arnold-litter-twitter-storm

and it looks it is attested for in the NY times (an American newspaper) too!

## NY times:

> There are safety tips ("Children should only use a toothbrush at the sink," and if they are younger than 6, they should use **a bit of toothpaste** the size of a baby pea); a discussion of tongues, including the "geographic tongue" that resembles a map, with red patches and white edges; and even a look at the mineral-laden saliva that forms tartar.
>   The New York Times - Health 3
>
> Source: http://www.nytimes.com/2004/05/25/health/books-on-health-good-teeth-good-health.html

Other common collocates:

[image]

Source: https://ludwig.guru/s/a+bit+of+toothpaste

Comment: Yes, but what about the central question?

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Which central question is that? I believe whether the app is right or wrong is irrelevant as Mari-LouA pointed out they're both grammatical, are they not? I attested for the usage of "a bit of toothpaste" (which answer's the OP's question; they can form their own opinion to the "right answer"). But I think it's pretty pointless debating if the app is right if: 1) "a bit of toothpaste" is **grammatical** or 2) we are questioning the validty/reliability of said app.